# Explain the correlation between PPI and resolution

Tags: resolution, pixels

I understand this is a very novice question to ask but I just want to make sure I have a firm grasp on the concept(s)

Resolution is how many pixels displayed on a screen by height x width.

How does this relate to pixel per inch(es). I'm assuming bigger monitors have more ppi.

Comment: Other things being equal, bigger monitors will have less pixels per inch. A bigger monitor means more inches, so fewer pixels per inch.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in saying that resolution is screen width x height (in pixels).

Pixels Per Inch (PPI), will actually get smaller as your screen gets bigger.  PPI is a measure of [pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density).  As the area a screen covers gets smaller, the pixels are more densely packed and so the PPI goes up.

Comment: Which can make the image sharper?

Comment: Typically, a higher density (higher res or smaller screen) will look better.

Comment: Last question: how is PPI calculated

Comment: For screens, the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density#Calculation_of_monitor_PPI) says it is the diagonal resolution/diagonal size